# Generic htaccess rewrite: always use https and www

Tags: .htaccess

I am searching for a **generic** htaccess rewrite which forces the user to use https **and** www. Hence, the following URLs should all be rewritten to https://www.domain.tld/some/path:

- http://domain.tld/some/path
- http://www.domain.tld/some/path
- https://domain.tld/some/path
- https://www.domain.tld/some/path

It should be a generic solution, so that the domain name is not contained in the rule. Most probably, the rule will contain something like `%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}` or `%1/$1`. Please describe why you use the one or the other.

Although there are tons of questions similar to this one, I did not find a solution which combines both - https and www redirection. Hope you can help.

**Edit 1:**

I tried the solutions by @anubhava, but I am getting a "too many redirects" error. Since the site is a Magento site, the htaccess is slightly more difficult. The following are the two mod_rewrite sections which I tried:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

############################################
## enable rewrites

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

############################################
## you can put here your magento root folder
## path relative to web root

    #RewriteBase /magento/

############################################
## uncomment next line to enable light API calls processing

#    RewriteRule ^api/([a-z][0-9a-z_]+)/?$ api.php?type=$1 [QSA,L]

############################################
## rewrite API2 calls to api.php (by now it is REST only)

    RewriteRule ^api/rest api.php?type=rest [QSA,L]

############################################
## workaround for HTTP authorization
## in CGI environment

    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

############################################
## TRACE and TRACK HTTP methods disabled to prevent XSS attacks

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRAC[EK]
    RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]

############################################
## redirect for mobile user agents

    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mobiledirectoryhere/.*$
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mobiledirectoryhere/ [L,R=302]

############################################
## always send 404 on missing files in these folders

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/

############################################
## never rewrite for existing files, directories and links

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

############################################
## rewrite everything else to index.php

    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

And the second version:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

############################################
## enable rewrites

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
    RewriteRule ^ https://www.domain.tld%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

############################################
## you can put here your magento root folder
## path relative to web root

    #RewriteBase /magento/

############################################
## uncomment next line to enable light API calls processing

#    RewriteRule ^api/([a-z][0-9a-z_]+)/?$ api.php?type=$1 [QSA,L]

############################################
## rewrite API2 calls to api.php (by now it is REST only)

    RewriteRule ^api/rest api.php?type=rest [QSA,L]

############################################
## workaround for HTTP authorization
## in CGI environment

    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

############################################
## TRACE and TRACK HTTP methods disabled to prevent XSS attacks

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRAC[EK]
    RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]

############################################
## redirect for mobile user agents

    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mobiledirectoryhere/.*$
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mobiledirectoryhere/ [L,R=302]

############################################
## always send 404 on missing files in these folders

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/

############################################
## never rewrite for existing files, directories and links

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

############################################
## rewrite everything else to index.php

    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Any ideas?

**Edit 2:**

Just setting up Magento to use https for secure and unsecure base URL as proposed by @anubhava does not solve the problem. The URL http://www.domain.tld/some/path is then redirected to https://www.domain.tld instead of https://www.domain.tld/some/path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear your browser cache and restart your browser first.

#### Magento setting change

Open admin panel and visit **`System -> Configration -> Web`** panel and set `Base URL` (for both secured and unsecured) as `https://www.domain.tld/`.

then set

`Auto-redirect to Base URL` = No

`Use Secure URLs in Frontend` = Yes

`Use Secure URLs in Admin` = Yes

Save your settings, clear your Magento cache

#### Magento .htaccess change

Put this code in your `.htaccess` in the base magento directory just below RewriteBase line:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Will test that later, but as I wrote in the question, I would prefer a generic solution...

Comment: As you can see this is as generic as possible. Nothing is hardcoded here.

Comment: Since I combined 2 different rules into one that is why I used the actual hostname instead of `%{HTTP_HOST}` variable. If you want to avoid that then above rule needs to be divided into 2 different rewrite rules.

Comment: Maybe you want to add this as a second solution to your answer?

Comment: For Magento you might not even need these rules since you define base URLs for secured and unsecured access in `Settings -> Configration -> Web`. Pls check www.siteground.com/tutorials/magento/magento_ssl.htm

Comment: My Magento tests are working fine with Magento settings as I wrote here. Q1. Did you comment out these earlier suggested rewrite rules? Q2. Did you update both `Base URL` fields (secured and unsecured) as `https://www.domain.tld/`?

Comment: @Simon: I got your message today. Pls leave your comment here on on this thread, will keep checking.

Comment: Thanks @anubhava. I think everything is in my edited question. A1: Yes, I did. A2: Yes, I did. Still same problem as described in Edit 2...

Comment: @Simon: I am away from home computer (where I have Magento running), will check the problem on my computer and post back my findings here.

Comment: @Simon: Please check my Update above. I believe this would take care of all the issues for you.

Comment: Thanks @anubhava. Your option 1 and 2 lead to a "too many redirects" error. Now I use the first part of option 2, the settings from option 3 and (and this is important!) I additionally set the option "Auto-redirect to Base URL" to "No". If you update your answer accordingly, I will accept it ;)

Comment: @Simon: That's great to know. I edited my answer to add this `"Auto-redirect to Base URL" to "No"` option.

Comment: Thanks @anubhava. Accepted it now although I am a bit sceptical because option 1 and 2 lead to the "too many redirects" error. Anyway, my solution is in the comments, that's enough :-)

Comment: @Simon: For the sake of future visitors to this question, I will remove option 1 and keep only 1st half of the option 2.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # non www to https://www...
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

    # non https to http
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

The first rewrite rule checks if the hostname starts with www and if not, redirects using https and prepends www to the hostname. The flag R=301 signals apache to use a HTTP 301 permanent redirect, the L causes mod_rewrite to stop processing the rule set. For details, have a look at the documentation: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/

The second rewrite rule catches requests with www but without https://. Hostname and path remain unchanged. Thanks to Nicolás Echániz and Joseph Scott's blog on http://joseph.randomnetworks.com/2004/07/22/redirect-to-ssl-using-apaches-htaccess/ for pointing out the second rule.

Comment: This does not work for `https://domain.tld/some/path`. Additionally, `http://domain.tld/some/path` is redirected to `https://www.domain.tld` - the `$1` does not seem to work.

Comment: What webserver are you using? Just tried it successfully on Apache 2.2.14 on Win7, the $1 works as expected.